# find the angle of intersection between the curve?

Tags: complex-analysis

The straight line $L_1 : x =0 ,  L_2 : y =0$ and  $L_3 : x+y = 1$ are  mapped by the  transformation  $w = z^2$ into the  curves  $C_1,C_2 $and $ C_3$  respectively .the  angle  of intersection  between the curve at $w= 0$  is

choose the correct option

$a) 0$

$b) \frac{\pi}{4}$

$c) \frac{\pi}{2}$

$d) \pi$

my attempts  : i know  that the  transformation $w = z^k$  magnifies  the  angle  $k$ times...as  here  i am confused  how  to find the  angle  of intersection,?

Any hints/solution will be  appreciated

Comment: I think you should make it more clear, are you asking to find the angle between the only two curves containing 0 right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$C_3$ does not pass the complex zero, (why?) so the question is what's the angle between $C_1$ and $C_2$. They are images of $L_1$ and $L_2$, respectively, and these two intersect  at an angle $\pi/2$ - they are the real and the imaginary axes. So their images intersect at $\pi $, alias $0$ - one of them is a positive and the other one is a negative 'half' of the real axis.

Comment: but in question it is intersection of $C_1,C_2,C_3$ and also why $C_3$ is not passing through $0$ in $w$ plane

Comment: @HoneyKumar Comment: the problem statement, as presented above, does _not_ say it's about an intersection of _all three_ curves. An implicit part of the problem is to find which curves do intersect at origin.

Comment: @HoneyKumar Hint: do you know how the square function $w=z^2$ transforms the modulus of its argument $|z|$ to a modulus of its value $|w|$...? If so, what are possible values of $|z|$ for complex numbers $z$ defined by the $C_3$ curve's points?

Comment: Made a mistake in the comment above. The last question should read: 'what are possible values of $|z|$ for complex numbers $z$ defined by the $L_3$ curve's points?'